# Tradingview in Pine Script the strategy position size don't work

Tags: pine-script

i have a simple strategy and i wanto to open OR 1 long position OR 1 short position.
I don´t want to open, for example, a short position when already have one long position open.

SO, my code is:

`strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, stop=livelloIngressoLong, when = strategy.position_size == 0)`

and

`strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, stop=livelloIngressoShort, when = strategy.position_size == 0)`

BUT they don't work. You can see screenshot add. When open a short it open a long but if short is open strategy.position_size is not 0 ! So why open a long? i can't belive it!

I have also tried with some variations like :

```
if strategy.position_size == 0
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, stop=livelloIngressoLong)
```

OR

````
longCondition = Strategy.position_size == 0
if longCondition
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, stop=livelloIngressoLong)```



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFkex.png
````

Answer (score 0):

The `when` argument specify when generate the entry order. But stop order can be executed later when stop price condition will be reached.
The fix for your case can be:

```
longCondition = Strategy.position_size == 0
if longCondition
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, stop=livelloIngressoLong)
else
    strategy.cancel("Long")
```